# How to print a list of dates asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, for-loop

I'm trying to print a list of dates using a for loop. I'm getting an error saying 'AddDays' is not a member of 'System.Array'.

```
 Dim payDates(10) as Date

  For index As Integer = 1 to 10
        Redim Preserve payDates(index) 
        payDates(index) = payDates.AddDays(1)
        index +=1
  NEXT

  Response.Write(payDates)
```

Comment: As said in answers the array is not a date or datetime object so you can not use AddDays without first referencing the index.
But I belive you are on the wrong track, the ReDim is probably not wanted.
Can you post example of what you want `Response.Write(payDates)` to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no vb expert, but you need to access the index of the array, not the array itself:

```
Dim payDates(10) as Date

  For index As Integer = 1 to 10
        Redim Preserve payDates(index) 
        payDates(index) = payDates(index).AddDays(1)
        index +=1
  NEXT

  Response.Write(payDates)
```

Also you migzht want to write every date. In this case change you code to this:

```
Dim payDates(10) as Date

  For index As Integer = 1 to 10
        Redim Preserve payDates(index) 
        payDates(index) = payDates(index).AddDays(1)
        Response.Write(payDates(index))
        index +=1
  NEXT
```

In essence:
`payDates` is of type `System.Array`
`payDates(index)` contains a `DateTime` variable at the position index, where index is of type `int`

Answer (score 0):

Well, `AddDays` *isn't* a member of `System.Array`.  But you're trying to call it anyway:

```
payDates.AddDays(1)
```

If you're trying to get a modified date, reference the date element of the array.  Something like this:

```
payDates(index).AddDays(1)
```

(Note that if you're looking to display this information on a web page, it's a lot better to set the information on elements of that page than to use `Response.Write()`.  You have very little control over where `Response.Write()` emits its output in the resulting page.)